# How do I hide columns and set widths based on a string in the first row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of workbooks with specific strings in the first row. So, for example I, say I have "Dog", "Cat", "Squirrel", and "Fish" in rows A - D. I would like to have a macro that searches for the values 'Dog' and 'Squirrel', and hide the columns, and then subsequently set the width of "Cat" and "Fish" to a value of 11.

I cannot just use column numbers because they are not consistent across all my workbooks. Thanks for your help.

```
Sub HideColumn1()
If Range("B4").Value = 0 Then
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Before you can hide and resize the columns, you first need to identify which columns need work.  I recommend making a loop that looks at each column and stores the column number in a specially named variable.  Once you've categorized all the columns, then you can hide/resize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Range("A1:D1") to your desired range or something more dynamic:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim hiddenRng As Range, widthRng As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:D1")

    If cell = "Dog" Or cell = "Squirrel" Then

        If (hiddenRng Is Nothing) Then
            Set hiddenRng = cell
        Else
            Set hiddenRng = Union(hiddenRng, cell)
        End If

    End If

    If cell = "Cat" Or cell = "Fish" Then

        If (widthRng Is Nothing) Then
            Set widthRng = cell
        Else
            Set widthRng = Union(widthRng, cell)
        End If

    End If

Next cell

If (Not hiddenRng Is Nothing) Then hiddenRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
If (Not widthRng Is Nothing) Then widthRng.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 11
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding a sub for hiding columns separately. Getting error of "range of object global failed". Sub Hide_Column()
Range("A,C:AV,AY:BA,BJ:BR").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub

Comment: your range is not a range. Use Range("AC:AV,AY:BA,BJ:BR").Select

Answer (score 0):

here is another example

```
Sub hideColumns()
Dim iRow, iCol As Integer
iRow = 1
iCol = 1

Dim cat, dog, fish, squirrel As String

cat = "Cat"
dog = "Dog"
fish = "Fish"
squirrel = "Squirrel"

Do While Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> ""
    If Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = dog Or Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = squirrel Then
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = cat Or Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = fish Then
        Cells(iRow, iCol).EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 11
    Else
        'did not find anything do somthing
    End If

iCol = iCol + 1
Loop
End Sub
```